# Don't show column name when validator returns an error

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, validation

I have the following code:

```
$this->form->setValidators(array(
    'email'   => new sfValidatorAnd(
        array(
            new sfValidatorEmail(array(), array(
                'invalid' => 'Enter a valid email address.',)),
            new sfValidatorDoctrineUnique(array(
                'model'=>'Users',
                'column'=>'email',
                ), array(
                'invalid' => 'This email is already being used.',
                )),
        ),
        array(),
        array(
                'required' => 'Required',
        )
    ),
//...
```

and when the email is not unique, it returns the following error: `email: This email is already being used.` But I don't want that `email:` in front of the message.
Is there a way I can stop showing the column name?

Can I get some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a special of sfValidatorDoctrineUnique, so it may be necessary to test uniqueness over more than one column.

You have to override the doClean() method to prevent this line (at the end) :

```
throw new sfValidatorErrorSchema($this, array($columns[0] => $error));
```

Further informations :

- [sfValidatorDoctrineUnique source](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/validator/sfValidatorDoctrineUnique.class.php#L116)
- http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/91044/

Comment: I use this and it shows the **column name** when using `sfValidatorDoctrineUnique`

Comment: Yes - you are right, the problem is caused by sfValidatorDoctrineUnique's doClean method here:  **throw new sfValidatorErrorSchema($this, array($columns[0] => $error));**  Imho the only solution is to override this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `throw_global_error` option to the `sfValidatorDoctrineUnique`, in order to throw your error and don't display the `<column>:`:

```
  new sfValidatorDoctrineUnique(
    array('throw_global_error' => true, 'column' => 'email'),
    array('invalid' => 'Custom message')
  )
```

Hope it's helpful.

Best regard.